# In a method which passes another method as an argument, why does the passes argument not need its argument passed?

Tags: swift, function

I made a method which passes an integer and boolean method as an argument(This method requires an integer as an argument). When I called this method and passed the integer and boolean method the code worked without requiring me to pass the integer in the boolean method, why is this?

(The code below is not my own and taken from Apple's introduction to Swift resource)

```
func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> Bool{ 

    for item in list{
        if condition(item){
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanTen(number:Int) -> Bool{
    return number < 10
}

var numbers = [20,19,2,30,12]
hasAnyMatches(list: numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

For example in this case, lessThanTen needs an integer to be passed as an argument, yet when I call hasAnyMatches I did not pass an integer to lessThanTen. Why is it that despite this the code still works?

Comment: The function itself is passed as the argument. It is then called at `if condition(item){...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first understand what really *is* a method/function reference.

Usually when functions are taught to beginners some people would use the function machine analogy. Hopefully you heard of that. A function is like a machine. It takes some inputs (parameters), processes the inputs, and spits something out (return value). And there are lots of these machines in a program.

A function reference, in this analogy, is like an arrow pointing to where the function machine is. It's like saying "this machine!" or "that machine over there!".

So why don't you need the parameters?

Because the parameters of a function are supplied by the function that takes the function reference. If the parameters were supplied by the caller, there would be no point in passing a function reference, right?

Let's consider this code:

```
func add(a: Int, b: Int) -> Int { return a + b }

func someFunc(_ param: (Int, Int) -> Int) {
    // some code
}
```

Calling `someFunc` with `add(a: 1, b: 2)` is pointless here because you could just write `3` instead. But if you pass `add`, `someFunc` can call `add` with any parameter it wants.

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty clear from your method definition:

```
for item in list{
  if condition(**item**){
   return true
  }
}
```

You are sending element(Int) from list array to condition method.